# Why does't my code print the output?

Tags: python, math

```
    multiple_one = 3.0
multiple_two = 5.0
multiple_answer = 1
while ( multiple_answer < 1000):
     number_of_multiples = 0
     checking_multiple = 1000.0
     if  (checking_multiple / multiple_one).is_integer:
         number_of_multiples += 1
     elif (checking_multiple / multiple_one).is_integer:
         number_of_multiples += 1
     checking_multiple -= 1 
print number_of_multiples
```

My code is suppose to print out how many multiples there are but keeps failing. Why is that ?

Comment: for starters you initialise `number_of_multiplies` to `0` on every iteration so any modification in your `if` line will be thrown away, ditto for `checking_multiple`

Comment: You're not changing `multiple_answer` at all. You will never exit the loop that way.

Comment: Also your `if` and `elif` are completely the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never changing `multiple_answer` so it is always less than 1000 so you are stuck in an infinite loop in the while statement. Do you want to count the number of times you multiplied? If so, you want to change

```
multiple_one = 3.0
multiple_two = 5.0
multiple_answer = 1
while ( multiple_answer < 1000):
     number_of_multiples = 0
     checking_multiple = 1000.0
     if  (checking_multiple / multiple_one).is_integer:
         number_of_multiples += 1
     elif (checking_multiple / multiple_one).is_integer:
         number_of_multiples += 1
     checking_multiple -= 1 
print number_of_multiples
```

to be:

```
multiple_one = 3.0
multiple_two = 5.0
multiple_answer = 1
while ( number_of_multiples < 1000):
     checking_multiple = 1000.0
     if  (checking_multiple / multiple_one).is_integer:
         number_of_multiples += 1
     elif SOMETHING_DIFFERENT:
         SOMETHING_ESLE_DIFFERENT 
print number_of_multiples
```

This way you are not resetting `number_of_multiples` in each iteration and you are checking the while loop against something that is changing based on the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is getting stuck in an infinite loop. You start looping here:

```
while ( multiple_answer < 1000):
```

but never update `multiple_answer` so your loop never finishes.